# What are the different spawns of end dungeons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I went ahead to upgrade to 1.9 and went to the end to find some of the nice loot from the new end cities. I went to like three different end cities, one was small the other two were kind of big. I found that all of the end ships were the exact same (not the loot but the size). So my question is what are the different spawns of the end dungeons and which one of the has the new elytra wings? My other question was: what is the spawn rule for the end dungeon?

After asking this question I went back and found like 2 other dungeons and they don't have the end ship!

[image]

My Solution:

I used `admist` to find some spawns and this was my photo (there are quite some as the key is 2000 blocks):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All end cities have a main tower. Some cities just contain this tower, but others have various rooms, towers, and pathways branching from them. (This is generated randomly). Each room has its particular function (see the different rooms [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city#Structure)). An end city has a *chance* to spawn as long as it's in the end and there is land.

Attached to each city, there is a random chance that a [end ship](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city#End_ship) will spawn. And, in every end ship, there is an elytra in an item frame. However, elytra cannot be found in the end city itself.

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city) (I suggest reading that page)

Comment: What are the spawn odds, like you have to be 300 blocks away? Or like something like that?

Comment: Whenever you load a chunk in the end, there is a chance (a low one) that an end city will be generated there, as long as it fits the necessary requirements.

Comment: Ok thanks, but you said it is a low chance, that is quite obvious, but like what exacly are the odds, like EX: Stronghold, only 2 per world

Comment: I have no idea (Probably <1% per chunk). I don't think there's a limit on how many there can be in a world, though.